# Receive PHP code with an POST request

Tags: php

I need to send a POST request to another file called `global.php`, for this I try this code below:

```
$url = 'global.php';
$data = array('stack' => 'overflow');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

This is the `global.php` file that should process the request:

```
if(isset($_POST['stack'])){
echo 'exists';
}else{
echo 'error';
}
```

The problem is that instead of the command `var_dump ($ result);` show **exists**, it shows the PHP code? how can I solve this problem?

And why when I try to do the same thing using `ajax` it returns me the text **exists** and not PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use full url, to process php file through server.

```
$url = 'http://YOURURL.com/global.php';
```

AJAX call is made from browser, to absolute URL, thats why You are getting desired response.

Comment: In my case, I'm using localhost... And both files: index.php (that have the POST code) and global.php (that have the text) is in same folder... In the end Both of them will go to my server online... In this case I will receive the PHP code or the result?

Comment: if You provide full URL to file_get_content, then You will get result. If You provide only filename, then you get PHP code.